# What is SAML token and FedAuth cookie?

Tags: cookies, sharepoint-2013, saml

I am new to claim based authentication. Can anyone please explain what a SAML token and FedAuth cookie is? And what is relation between them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SAML Token is a piece of XML, containing information about the identity of a user. It is received from an Idp or STS. Idp is short for Identity Provider and STS is short for Security Token Service. It's really just two names for the same thing.

When using sharepoint with WS-federation, a SAML token is received from an STS. Then a session is established in sharepoint by setting a cookie named FedAuth.